# address not mapped to object at address (nil)

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmp

I can compile my FORTRAN code successfully but receive the following error message when I try to run it.

```
Loading compiler version 2022.0.2
Loading tbb version 2021.5.1
Loading compiler-rt version 2022.0.2
Loading oclfpga version 2022.0.2
  Load "debugger" to debug DPC++ applications with the gdb-oneapi debugger.
  Load "dpl" for additional DPC++ APIs: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDPL
Loading mkl version 2022.0.2
Loading mpi version 2021.5.1
 l4
 l4
 l2
 l2
 before mpi
 before mpi
 before parameterization
 before openmp
 before mpi
 before mpi
 before parameterization
 before openmp
[login:12832:0:12868] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   RANK 0 PID 12831 RUNNING AT login
=   KILLED BY SIGNAL: 9 (Killed)
===================================================================================

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   RANK 1 PID 12832 RUNNING AT login
=   KILLED BY SIGNAL: 11 (Segmentation fault)
===================================================================================
```

It seems that the subroutine TRANSPORT part calls some invalid arrays with null pointer because the code stops before the OpenMP part in this subroutine. However, I did not see any mistake in the subroutine. Would anyone help me check my following code and give me some suggestions on how to improve it? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code.

```
MODULE COMPU
CONTAINS
SUBROUTINE LATTICECONSTANTink(lr,lk)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER              ::             dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)    
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             lr(3,3)                           
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             lk(3,3)                           
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             tr(4)                             
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             pi                                
tr(1) = lr(2,2)*lr(3,3)-lr(3,2)*lr(2,3)
tr(2) = lr(3,1)*lr(2,3)-lr(2,1)*lr(3,3)
tr(3) = lr(2,1)*lr(3,2)-lr(3,1)*lr(2,2)
tr(4) = lr(1,1)*tr(1)+lr(1,2)*tr(2)+lr(1,3)*tr(3)
lk(1,1) = tr(1)/tr(4)
lk(1,2) = tr(2)/tr(4)
lk(1,3) = tr(3)/tr(4)
tr(1) = lr(3,2)*lr(1,3)-lr(1,2)*lr(3,3)
tr(2) = lr(1,1)*lr(3,3)-lr(3,1)*lr(1,3)
tr(3) = lr(3,1)*lr(1,2)-lr(1,1)*lr(3,2)
tr(4) = lr(2,1)*tr(1)+lr(2,2)*tr(2)+lr(2,3)*tr(3)
lk(2,1) = tr(1)/tr(4)
lk(2,2) = tr(2)/tr(4)
lk(2,3) = tr(3)/tr(4)
tr(1) = lr(1,2)*lr(2,3)-lr(2,2)*lr(1,3)
tr(2) = lr(2,1)*lr(1,3)-lr(1,1)*lr(2,3)
tr(3) = lr(1,1)*lr(2,2)-lr(2,1)*lr(1,2)
tr(4) = lr(3,1)*tr(1)+lr(3,2)*tr(2)+lr(3,3)*tr(3)
lk(3,1) = tr(1)/tr(4)
lk(3,2) = tr(2)/tr(4)
lk(3,3) = tr(3)/tr(4)
pi = DACOS(-1.0d0)
lk = lk * 2.0d0 * pi
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE LATTICECONSTANTink

SUBROUTINE MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(di,ou,i1,i2)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER              ::             dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)      
INTEGER                         ::             di                                  
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ou(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             i1(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             i2(:,:)                             
INTEGER                         ::             i, j, k
ou = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, di, 1
   DO j = 1, di, 1
      DO k = 1, di, 1
         ou(i,j) = ou(i,j)+i1(j,k)*i2(k,j)
      END DO
   END DO
END DO

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX
END MODULE COMPU

MODULE TRANS
CONTAINS
SUBROUTINE TRANSPORT(n1,n2,n3,dk,ra,ch,nm,te,nb,po,tv,lr,ei,ks,ol,t2,t3)
USE COMPU
USE BLAS95
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER              ::             dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)      
INTEGER                         ::             n1                                  
INTEGER                         ::             n2                                  
INTEGER                         ::             n3                                  
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             dk(3)                               
INTEGER                         ::             ra(2)                               
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             ch(3)                               
INTEGER                         ::             nm                                  
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             te                                  
INTEGER                         ::             nb                                  
INTEGER                         ::             po(3)                               
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE            ::             tv(:,:)                             
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             lr(3,3)                             
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE     ::             ei(:)                               
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ks(:,:,:)                           
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ol(:,:,:)                           
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t2(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t3(:)                               
INTEGER                         ::             i, j, k, l
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             kc(3)                               
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             kb                                  
COMPLEX (KIND=dp)               ::             ic                                  
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             sr(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ll(:,:,:)                           
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ls(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             rl(:,:,:)                           
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             rs(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             th(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             rg(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ag(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             m1(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             m2(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             m3(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp)               ::             pf                                  
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             l1(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             l2(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             r1(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             r2(:,:)                             
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             fd(3)                               
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             tr(:,:)                             
INTEGER                         ::             lwork, info
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE            ::             ipiv(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             work(:)

print*,'before parameterization'
kb = 1.0d0
ic = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 1.0d0)
kc(1) = (n1-1)*dk(1)
kc(2) = (n2-1)*dk(2)
kc(3) = (n3-1)*dk(3)
k = ra(2) - ra(1) + 1
ALLOCATE (sr(k,k))
ALLOCATE (ls(k,k))
ALLOCATE (rs(k,k))
ALLOCATE (rg(k,k))
ALLOCATE (ag(k,k))
ALLOCATE (th(nb,nb))
ALLOCATE (ll(3,k,k))
ALLOCATE (rl(3,k,k))
ALLOCATE (m1(k,k))
ALLOCATE (m2(k,k))
ALLOCATE (m3(k,k))
ALLOCATE (ipiv(k))
lwork = k
ALLOCATE (work(lwork))
ALLOCATE (l1(k,k))
ALLOCATE (l2(k,k))
ALLOCATE (r1(k,k))
ALLOCATE (r2(k,k))
ALLOCATE (tr(k,k))
t2 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
t3 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
print*,'before openmp'
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(i,j,l,pf,th,ll,sr,rl,ls,rs,rg,ag,l1,l2,r1,r2,ipiv,work,lwork,info,fd,tr,m1,m2,m3)&
!$OMP             SHARED(nm,nb,po,kb,ic,kc,tv,lr,ol,ks,k,ei,ra,ch,te) REDUCTION(+:t2,t3)
DO i = 1, nm, 1
   th = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
print*,'s5'
   DO j = 1, nb, 1
      DO l = 1, (po(1)*2+1)*(po(2)*2+1)*(po(3)*2+1), 1
         pf = EXP(ic*(kc(1)*(tv(1,l)*lr(1,1)+tv(2,l)*lr(2,1)+tv(3,l)*lr(3,1))&
              +kc(2)*(tv(1,l)*lr(1,2)+tv(2,l)*lr(2,2)+tv(3,l)*lr(3,2))&
              +kc(3)*(tv(1,l)*lr(1,3)+tv(2,l)*lr(2,3)+tv(3,l)*lr(3,3))))
         th(:,j) = th(:,j)+pf*((ei(i)+ic)*ol(:,j,l)-ks(:,j,l))
      END DO
   END DO
print*,'s1'
   ll(1,:,:) = th(ra(1):ra(2),ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k)                                     
   m1 = th(ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k,ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k)                                        
   CALL ZGETRF(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,ra(2)-ra(1)+1,ipiv,info)
   CALL ZGETRI(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,ra(2)-ra(1)+1,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
   ll(2,:,:) = m1
   ll(3,:,:) = th(ra(1)-k:ra(2)-k,ra(1):ra(2))                                     
   sr = th(ra(1):ra(2),ra(1):ra(2))                                                
   rl(1,:,:) = th(ra(1):ra(2),ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k)                                     
   m1 = th(ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k,ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k)                                        
   CALL ZGETRF(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,ra(2)-ra(1)+1,ipiv,info)
   CALL ZGETRI(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,ra(2)-ra(1)+1,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
   rl(2,:,:) = m1
   rl(3,:,:) = th(ra(1)+k:ra(2)+k,ra(1):ra(2))                                     
   m2 = ll(1,:,:)
   m3 = ll(2,:,:)
   CALL MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,m2,m3)
   m2 = m1
   m3 = ll(3,:,:)
   CALL MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,m2,m3)
   ls = m1                                                                         
   m2 = rl(1,:,:)
   m3 = rl(2,:,:)
   CALL MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,m2,m3)
   m2 = m1
   m3 = rl(3,:,:)
   CALL MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,m2,m3)
   rs = m1                                                                         
   rg = sr-ls-rs
   CALL ZGETRF(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,ra(2)-ra(1)+1,rg,ra(2)-ra(1)+1,ipiv,info)
   CALL ZGETRI(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,rg,ra(2)-ra(1)+1,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
   DO j = 1, ra(2)-ra(1)+1, 1
      ag(j,:) = DCONJG(rg(:,j))
   END DO
   l1 = ls
   DO j = 1, ra(2)-ra(1)+1, 1
      l2(j,:) = DCONJG(l1(:,j))
   END DO
   m2 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, ra(2)-ra(1)+1
      m2(j,j) = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 1.0d0)
   END DO
   m3 = l1 - l2
   CALL MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,m2,m3)
   ls = m1
   r1 = rs
   DO j = 1, ra(2)-ra(1)+1, 1
      r2(j,:) = DCONJG(r1(:,j))
   END DO
   m2 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, ra(2)-ra(1)+1, 1
      m2(j,j) = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 1.0d0)
   END DO
   m3 = r1 - r2
   CALL MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,m2,m3)
   rs = m1
print*,'s2'
   fd(1) = 1.0d0/(EXP((ei(i)-ch(1))/te/kb)+1.0d0)
   fd(2) = 1.0d0/(EXP((ei(i)-ch(3))/te/kb)+1.0d0)
   IF (fd(1) > fd(2)) THEN
      fd(3) = fd(1)-fd(2)
   ELSE IF (fd(1) == fd(2)) THEN
           fd(3) = 0.0d0
   ELSE
      fd(3) = fd(2)-fd(1)
   END IF
   m2 = ls
   m3 = ag
   CALL MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,m2,m3)
   m2 = m1
   m3 = rs
   CALL MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,m2,m3)
   m2 = m1
   m3 = rg
   CALL MULTIPLICATION_MATRIX(ra(2)-ra(1)+1,m1,m2,m3)
   tr = m1
print*,'s3'
   DO j = 1, ra(2)-ra(1)+1, 1
      t2(i) = t2(i)+tr(j,j)
   END DO
   t2(i) = t2(i)*fd(3)
print*,'s4'
   tr = rg - ag
   DO j = 1, ra(2)-ra(1)+1, 1
      t3(i) = t3(i)+tr(j,j)
   END DO
END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
print*,'after openmp'
DEALLOCATE (sr)
DEALLOCATE (ll)
DEALLOCATE (ls)
DEALLOCATE (rg)
DEALLOCATE (ag)
DEALLOCATE (rl)
DEALLOCATE (rs)
DEALLOCATE (th)
DEALLOCATE (ipiv)
DEALLOCATE (work)
DEALLOCATE (l1)
DEALLOCATE (l2)
DEALLOCATE (r1)
DEALLOCATE (r2)
DEALLOCATE (tr)
DEALLOCATE (m1)
DEALLOCATE (m2)
DEALLOCATE (m3)
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE TRANSPORT
END MODULE TRANS

PROGRAM QUANTUMTRANSPORT_NEGF
USE MPI
USE COMPU
USE TRANS
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER              ::             dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)      
INTEGER                         ::             ra(2)                               
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             ch(3)                               
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             mi                                  
INTEGER                         ::             nm                                  
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             te                                  
INTEGER                         ::             km(3)                               
INTEGER                         ::             ps(3)                               
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             lr(3,3)                             
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             lk(3,3)                             
INTEGER                         ::             na                                  
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE     ::             ap(:,:)                             
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE            ::             ns(:,:)                             
INTEGER                         ::             po(3)                               
INTEGER                         ::             nb                                  
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             p1(3)                               
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE            ::             p2(:,:)                             
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE            ::             tv(:,:)                             
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ok(:,:,:)                           
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             oo(:,:,:)                           
INTEGER                         ::             i, j, k, l, m, n                    
INTEGER                         ::             tc(4)                               
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             ti                                  
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             dk(3)                               
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ks(:,:,:)                           
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             ol(:,:,:)                           
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE     ::             ei(:)                               
REAL (KIND=dp)                  ::             pi                                  
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t2(:)                               
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             c2(:)                               
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             c3(:)                               
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             t3(:)                               
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             c4(:)                               
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             c5(:)                               
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE  ::             cc(:)                               
INTEGER                         ::             world_size, world_rank, ierr        

CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_size,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_rank,ierr)

IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(count_rate=tc(1))
   ti = REAL(tc(1))
END IF
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(tc(2))
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(tc(3))
END IF
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN (UNIT=3, FILE='INPUT.dat', STATUS='OLD')
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) ra
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) ch(1)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) ch(2)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) ch(3)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) mi
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) nm
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) te
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) km
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) ps
   CLOSE (UNIT=3)
   ch = ch * 3.67493036006967667962692106984d-2 !eV -> a.u.
   mi = mi * 3.67493036006967667962692106984d-2 !eV -> a.u.
END IF
CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(ra,2,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(ch,3,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(mi,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(nm,1,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(te,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(km,3,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN (UNIT=11, FILE='final.config', STATUS='OLD')
   READ (UNIT=11, FMT=*) na
   READ (UNIT=11, FMT=*)
   DO i = 1, 3, 1
      READ (UNIT=11, FMT=*) p1
      lr(i,:) = p1
   END DO
   READ (UNIT=11, FMT=*)
   ALLOCATE (ap(na,6))
   ALLOCATE (ns(3,na))
   DO i = 1, na, 1
      READ (UNIT=11, FMT=*) j, p1, k, l, m
      ap(i,4:6) = p1
      ns(1,i) = i
   END DO
   CLOSE (UNIT=11)
   
   DO i = 1, na, 1
      ap(i,1) = ap(i,4)*lr(1,1)+ap(i,5)*lr(2,1)+ap(i,6)*lr(3,1)
      ap(i,2) = ap(i,4)*lr(1,2)+ap(i,5)*lr(2,2)+ap(i,6)*lr(3,2)
      ap(i,3) = ap(i,4)*lr(1,3)+ap(i,5)*lr(2,3)+ap(i,6)*lr(3,3)
   END DO
   
   DO i = 1, na, 1
      DO j = i+1, na, 1
         IF (ap(i,ps(1)) > ap(j,ps(1))) THEN
             k = ns(1,i)
             ns(1,i) = ns(1,j)
             ns(1,j) = k
         ELSE IF (ap(i,ps(1)) == ap(j,ps(1))) THEN
                 IF (ap(i,ps(2)) > ap(j,ps(2))) THEN
                    k = ns(1,i)
                    ns(1,i) = ns(1,j)
                    ns(1,j) = k
                 ELSE IF (ap(i,ps(2)) == ap(i,ps(2))) THEN
                    IF (ap(i,ps(3)) > ap(j,ps(3))) THEN
                       k = ns(1,i)
                       ns(1,i) = ns(1,j)
                       ns(1,j) = k
                    END IF
                 END IF
         END IF
      END DO
   END DO
   DEALLOCATE (ap)
   ALLOCATE (p2(2,na))
   OPEN (UNIT=12, FILE='OUT.GAUSSIAN_BASIS_INDEX', FORM='UNFORMATTED', STATUS='OLD')
   READ (UNIT=12) i, j
   READ (UNIT=12) p2(:,1:na)
   DO i = 1, na, 1
      ns(2:3,i) = p2(:,i)
   END DO
   CLOSE (UNIT=12)
   DEALLOCATE (p2)
END IF
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN (UNIT=4, FILE='OUT.GAUSSIAN_H_T', FORM='UNFORMATTED', STATUS='OLD')
   OPEN (UNIT=6, FILE='OUT.GAUSSIAN_S_T', FORM='UNFORMATTED', STATUS='OLD')
   READ (UNIT=4) po, nb, lr
   READ (UNIT=6) po, nb, lr

   ALLOCATE (ok(nb,nb,(po(1)*2+1)*(po(2)*2+1)*(po(3)*2+1)))
   ALLOCATE (oo(nb,nb,(po(1)*2+1)*(po(2)*2+1)*(po(3)*2+1)))
END IF
CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(po,3,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(nb,1,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(lr,3*3,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
ALLOCATE (tv(3,(po(1)*2+1)*(po(2)*2+1)*(po(3)*2+1)))
ALLOCATE (ks(nb,nb,(po(1)*2+1)*(po(2)*2+1)*(po(3)*2+1)))
ALLOCATE (ol(nb,nb,(po(1)*2+1)*(po(2)*2+1)*(po(3)*2+1)))
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   DO i = 1, po(1)*2+1, 1
      DO j = 1, po(2)*2+1, 1
         DO k = 1, po(3)*2+1, 1
            l = (i-1)*(po(2)*2+1)*(po(3)*2+1)+(j-1)*(po(3)*2+1)+k
            READ (UNIT=4) tv(:,l)
            READ (UNIT=6) tv(:,l)
            DO m = 1, nb, 1
               READ (UNIT=4) ok(:,m,l)
               READ (UNIT=6) oo(:,m,l)
            END DO
         END DO
      END DO
   END DO
   DO i = 1, (po(1)*2+1)*(po(2)*2+1)*(po(3)*2+1), 1
      l = 0
      DO j = 1, na, 1
         DO k = 1, na, 1
            IF (ns(1,k) == j) THEN
               ks(:,l+1:l+ns(3,k)-ns(2,k)+1,i) = ok(:,ns(2,k):ns(3,k),i)
               ol(:,l+1:l+ns(3,k)-ns(2,k)+1,i) = oo(:,ns(2,k):ns(3,k),i)
               ks(l+1:l+ns(3,k)-ns(2,k)+1,:,i) = ok(ns(2,k):ns(3,k),:,i)
               ol(l+1:l+ns(3,k)-ns(2,k)+1,:,i) = oo(ns(2,k):ns(3,k),:,i)
               l = l + ns(3,k) - ns(2,k) + 1
            END IF
         END DO
      END DO
   END DO
   CLOSE (UNIT=4)
   CLOSE (UNIT=6)
   DEALLOCATE (ns)
   DEALLOCATE (ok)
   DEALLOCATE (oo)
END IF
print*,'l4'
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL LATTICECONSTANTink(lr,lk)
   IF (km(1) == 1) THEN
      dk(1) = 0.0d0
   ELSE
      dk(1) = DSQRT(lk(1,1)**2+lk(1,2)**2+lk(1,3)**2)/DBLE(km(1)-1)
   END IF
   IF (km(2) == 1) THEN
      dk(2) = 0.0d0
   ELSE
      dk(2) = DSQRT(lk(2,1)**2+lk(2,2)**2+lk(2,3)**2)/DBLE(km(2)-1)
   END IF
   IF (km(3) == 1) THEN
      dk(3) = 0.0d0
   ELSE
      dk(3) = DSQRT(lk(3,1)**2+lk(3,2)**2+lk(3,3)**2)/DBLE(km(3)-1)
   END IF
END IF
CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(dk,3,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
ALLOCATE (ei(nm))
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   DO i = 1, nm, 1
      ei(i) = mi+(i-1)*(ch(2)-mi)/DBLE(nm-1)
   END DO
END IF
print*,'l2'
CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(ei,nm,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(tc(4))
   OPEN (UNIT=10, FILE='output.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
   WRITE (UNIT=10, FMT='(A81)') 'Time for reading input parameters, atom positions, re-organising the Hamiltonian'
   WRITE (UNIT=10, FMT='(A62,F20.4,A7)') 'matrice, generating k points and broadcasting all parameters:', (tc(4)-tc(3))/ti, 'seconds'
END IF
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(tc(2))
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(tc(3))
END IF
ALLOCATE (t2(nm))
ALLOCATE (t3(nm))
print*,'before mpi'
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   ALLOCATE (c2(nm))
   c2 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   ALLOCATE (c3(nm))
   ALLOCATE (c4(nm))
   c4 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   ALLOCATE (c5(nm))
END IF
print*,'before mpi'
DO i = 1, km(1), 1
   DO j = 1, km(2), 1
      DO k = 1, km(3), 1
         IF (MOD((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k-1, world_size) /= world_rank) CYCLE
         CALL TRANSPORT(i,j,k,dk,ra,ch,nm,te,nb,po,tv,lr,ei,ks,ol,t2,t3)
         IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
            c2 = c2 + t2
            c4 = c4 + t3
            DO l = 1, world_size-1, 1
               IF ((i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k-1+l == km(1)*km(2)*km(2)) EXIT
               m = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + l + 100000
               CALL MPI_RECV(c3,nm,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,l,m,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
               c2 = c2 + c3
               n = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + l + 1000000
               CALL MPI_RECV(c5,nm,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,l,n,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
               c4 = c4 + c5
            END DO
         ELSE
            m = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + 100000
            CALL MPI_SEND(t2,nm,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,m,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
            n = (i-1)*km(2)*km(3)+(j-1)*km(3)+k + 1000000
            CALL MPI_SEND(t3,nm,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,n,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
         END IF
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
print*,'after mpi'
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   IF ((dk(1) /= 0) .AND. (dk(2) /= 0) .AND. (dk(3) /= 0)) THEN
      c2 = c2*dk(1)*dk(2)*dk(3)
      c4 = c4*dk(1)*dk(2)*dk(3)
   ELSE IF ((dk(1) /= 0) .AND. (dk(2) == 0) .AND. (dk(3) /= 0)) THEN
           c2 = c2*dk(1)*dk(3)
           c4 = c4*dk(1)*dk(3)
   ELSE IF ((dk(1) /= 0) .AND. (dk(2) /= 0) .AND. (dk(3) == 0)) THEN
           c2 = c2*dk(1)*dk(2)
           c4 = c4*dk(1)*dk(2)
   ELSE IF ((dk(1) == 0) .AND. (dk(2) /= 0) .AND. (dk(3) /= 0)) THEN
           c2 = c2*dk(2)*dk(3)
           c4 = c4*dk(2)*dk(3)
   ELSE IF ((dk(1) /= 0) .AND. (dk(2) == 0) .AND. (dk(3) == 0)) THEN
           c2 = c2*dk(1)
           c4 = c4*dk(1)
   ELSE IF ((dk(1) == 0) .AND. (dk(2) /= 0) .AND. (dk(3) == 0)) THEN
           c2 = c2*dk(2)
           c4 = c4*dk(2)
   ELSE IF ((dk(1) == 0) .AND. (dk(2) == 0) .AND. (dk(3) /= 0)) THEN
           c2 = c2*dk(3)
           c4 = c4*dk(3)
   END IF
END IF
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(tc(4))
   WRITE (UNIT=10, FMT='(A45,F8.4,A7)') 'Time for computing the transport properties:', (tc(4)-tc(3))/ti, 'seconds'
END IF
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   pi = DACOS(-1.0d0)
   ALLOCATE (cc(nm))
   cc = c2
   c2 = c2*(ch(2)-mi)/DBLE(nm-1)
   cc(1) = cc(1)/2.0d0
   DO i = nm, 1, -1
      cc(i) = cc(i)/2.0d0
      DO j = 1, i, 1
         cc(i) = cc(i) + cc(j)
      END DO
   END DO
   c4 = c4/2.0d0/pi*(-1.0d0)
END IF
!!!
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN (UNIT=8, FILE='charge_current.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
   OPEN (UNIT=9, FILE='dos.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
   WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT=*) 'Charge current with the unit of 2e^2/h'
   WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT='(A60)') 'The integrate of the charge current v.s. Fermi energy level'
   DO i = 1, nm, 1
      WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT=*) ei(i), c2(i)
   END DO
   WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT=*)
   WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT='(A59)') 'The integral of the charge current v.s. Fermi energy level'
   DO i = 1, nm, 1
      WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT=*) ei(i), cc(i)
   END DO
   DO i = 1, nm, 1
      WRITE (UNIT=9, FMT=*) 'DOS with the unit of States/eV'
      WRITE (UNIT=9, FMT=*) ei(i), IMAG(c4(i))
   END DO
   DEALLOCATE (c2)
   DEALLOCATE (c3)
   DEALLOCATE (c4)
   DEALLOCATE (c5)
   DEALLOCATE (cc)
   CLOSE (UNIT=8)
   CLOSE (UNIT=9)
   CLOSE (UNIT=10)
END IF
CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
DEALLOCATE (ks)
DEALLOCATE (tv)
DEALLOCATE (ol)
DEALLOCATE (ei)
DEALLOCATE (t2)
DEALLOCATE (t3)

STOP
END PROGRAM QUANTUMTRANSPORT_NEGF
```

Comment: run `dmesg` on the nodes where the MPI app is running and check if wheter it was killed by the `oom-killer`. `ALLOCATE(...)` can take a `STAT` argument to double check the array was indeed allocated, but I honestly do not know how this works with memory oversubscription. you can also try `ulimit -s unlimited` before `mpirun`, that will help if OpenMP threads allocate lot of memory of their (private) stack.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the suggestions.

I checked /etc/profile file and saw that 'ulimit -s unlimited' has already been added. I also modified my job submission file and it is shown below.
```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --partition=demo
#SBATCH --job-name=Quantumtransport
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=12
module load compiler/2022.0.2
module load mkl/2022.0.2
module load mpi/2021.5.1
mpirun ./NEGF
dmesg > sys_log.txt
```

Comment: @Gilles I still received the same error message. After I changed the setting for --partition to cpu. The previous error about 'Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))' was gone.  I am confused why it was that.

Comment: @Gilles On the other hand, I receive another new error message about the ZGETRI after I changed the setting for --partition to cpu. Here is the error message.
```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry to ZGETRI.
```
I checked the ZGETRI function in the subruotine TRANSPORT part but I did not find anything wrong. Would you please give me more suggestions to revise it?

Comment: Your code won't compile. t3 in subroutine TRANSPORT hasn't been given a type and implicit none is in force.

Comment: @Kieran test `info` to figure out which call fails, and print both the first and sixth argument.

Comment: @lastchance Thank you for the comment. I deleted t3 variable setting by mistake when I pasted my code here. I have modified it.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the suggestions. I checked output variable info from ZGETRF function and found that it was 1. I think that this means that the LU decomposition of the variable matrix 'm1' failed with some zero value on the diagonal term and this is also the reason why the following ZGETRI function failed. I am not sure how to sort it out because the matrix was read from other calculations and I cannot change it. Would you please give me some more suggestions?

Comment: that looks unrelated to the error reported by MKL, check https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d01/group__complex16_g_ecomputational_gab490cfc4b92edec5345479f19a9a72ca.html